# Error:java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'spcrId' available as request attribute

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I am trying to build simple spring mvc application for implementing CRUD operations. I am taking look at [this url](http://www.beingjavaguys.com/2013/07/spring-jdbc-template-with-spring-mvc.html) for reference.

My addSpcr.jsp file is:

```
<form method="POST" action="/insert" modelAttribute="spcr">
<h2 style="text-align:center">SPCR Details</h2>
<table style="width:100%" border="1px">
<tr>
    <td class="td_left">SPCR Id:</td>
    <!-- <td class="td_right"><input type="text" id="spcrId" name="spcrId"/></td> -->
    <td class="td_right"><form:input path="spcrId" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class="td_left">SPCR Header:</td>
    <!-- <td class="td_right"><textarea id="spcrId" name="spcrId" rows="2" style="width:95%"> </textarea></td> -->
    <td class="td_right"><form:input path="spcrHeader" /></td>
</tr>
```

and HomeController method is:

```
@RequestMapping("/addSpcr")
public ModelAndView showAddSpcr(@ModelAttribute SpcrDetails spcr){

    List<String> groupName = new ArrayList<String>();

    groupName.add("COBOL");
    groupName.add("YBN");
    groupName.add("power Builder");
    groupName.add("Jasper");
    groupName.add("Mail Merge");

    List<String> spcrStatus = new ArrayList<String>();

    spcrStatus.add("Not Started");
    spcrStatus.add("Analysis and Design");
    spcrStatus.add("In Progress");
    spcrStatus.add("Dependency with Onsite");
    spcrStatus.add("Coding Completed");
    spcrStatus.add("Testing Completed");
    spcrStatus.add("Delivered to Onsite");

    Map<String, List> map = new HashMap<String, List>();
    map.put("groupName", groupName);
    map.put("spcrStatus", spcrStatus);
    return new ModelAndView("addSpcr","map",map);

}
```

spring-servlet.xml:

```
 <!-- declare beans -->  
 <bean id="spcrDetailsDao" class="com.leader.unisys.dao.SpcrDetailsDaoImpl" /> 
 <bean id="spcrService" class="com.leader.unisys.services.SpcrServiceImpl" />
```

When I try to run my application its giving me error message as shown below:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'spcrId' available as request attribute
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.support.BindStatus.<init>(BindStatus.java:144)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.getBindStatus(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:168)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.getPropertyPath(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:188)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.getName(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:154)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.autogenerateId(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:141)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.resolveId(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:132)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.writeDefaultAttributes(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:116)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractHtmlElementTag.writeDefaultAttributes(AbstractHtmlElementTag.java:422)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.InputTag.writeTagContent(InputTag.java:142)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractFormTag.doStartTagInternal(AbstractFormTag.java:84)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.RequestContextAwareTag.doStartTag(RequestContextAwareTag.java:80)
    at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.jsp.addSpcr_jsp._jspx_meth_form_005finput_005f0(addSpcr_jsp.java:216)
    at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.jsp.addSpcr_jsp._jspService(addSpcr_jsp.java:116)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:395)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:339)
    .....
```

model class SpcrDetails.java

```
public class SpcrDetails {

private String spcrId;
private String spcrHeader;
private String groupName;
private Date startDate;
private Date endDate;
private Date releaseDate;
private int estimates;
private String spcrStatus;

//getters and setters
```

Its not mapping the names from jsp file to names of fields from pojo class. I am not getting what i did wrong here.

Comment: Above error message is clearly indicated that the “spcrId” bean does not exists

Comment: @tnadeV Its there in my pogo class. SpcrDetails.

Comment: your form tag will try to bind with a bean named spcr, do u have any other controller? with @RequestMapping("/spcr")

Answer (score 0):

```
<form method="POST" action="/insert" modelAttribute="spcr">
```

change this to

```
   <form method="POST" action="/insert" modelAttribute="addSpcr">
```

Comment: anyways you will need  to be modelAttribute="addSpcr", try removing id="spcrId" from jsp

Comment: id part is commented. So you can ignore it.

Comment: added some more code parts in the description for your reference.

Comment: Please refer the given url in the question. In map I am pasing drop down lists.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a `spcr`object for `addSpcr.jsp` because in your .jsp file you have `modelAttribute="spcr"`, so you need a model have a same name with `modalAttribute` value when you load Controller

Answer (score 0):

```
I am explain this error.please understand your mistack and solve.
1)**myjsppage.jsp**
<a href="insertaction">click</a>
2)Controller
@Requestmapping("/insertaction")
public String showpage(ModelMap model)
{
   model.addAttribute("student",new student);
   return "student"
}
3)student.jsp page
<form method="POST" action="/insert" modelAttribute="student">
//your code
```

model.addAttribute("**student**",new student);
modelAttribute="**student**"
bold represent must be same name.